# How to implement counter in Harris Corner Detection algorithm?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('maple.jpg')
half = cv.resize(img, (1200, 800), fx=0.1, fy=0.1)
gray = cv.cvtColor(half, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv.cornerHarris(gray, 2, 3, 0.08)
dst = cv.dilate(dst, None)
half[dst > 0.01 * dst.max()] = [0, 0, 255]
cv.imshow('dst', half)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I need to count the number of features detected by this code. The features appear as red dots in the image. I am extremely new to python and OpenCV. I have no idea how to implement the counter in this code.

Comment: Hey. You might want to have a look at 'approxPolyDP' function.

Comment: So instead of implementing a counter variable directly in the program, i'd be using this function to count the red dots in the resulting image, right?

Comment: There can be multiple ways to approach a problem. You can implement your own counting snippet but Usually, it is best to use inbuilt tools and libraries that provide the functionality instead of reinventing the wheel by yourself. This safe bet because the internal tools are far more optimized.

Comment: i am still a beginner so its a little difficult for me to use that function. i dont know where to start.

Comment: Might as well accept the answer if you think it to solve your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet that might help you.

```
# Python code to detect an arrow (seven-sided shape) from an image. 
import numpy as np 
import cv2 
   
# Reading image 
img2 = cv2.imread('arrow.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 
   
# Reading same image in another variable and  
# converting to gray scale. 
img = cv2.imread('arrow.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
   
# Converting image to a binary image  
# (black and white only image). 
_,threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 110, 255,  
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 
   
# Detecting shapes in image by selecting region  
# with same colors or intensity. 
contours,_=cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
   
# Searching through every region selected to  
# find the required polygon. 
for cnt in contours : 
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt) 
   
    # Shortlisting the regions based on there area. 
    if area > 400:  
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,  
                                  0.009 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True) 
   
        # Checking if the no. of sides of the selected region is 7. 
        if(len(approx) == 7):  
            cv2.drawContours(img2, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5) 
   
# Showing the image along with outlined arrow. 
cv2.imshow('image2', img2)  
   
# Exiting the window if 'q' is pressed on the keyboard. 
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the image used in the snippet:

[image]

Here is the [reference link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-detect-polygons-in-an-image-using-opencv/)

P.S - Do upvote the answer if it is helpful.